# Is this series expressible in terms of Gauss' hypergeometric function?

Tags: special-functions

How we can express this series $$F(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{(a)_nn!}$$ in terms of Gauss' hypergeometric function?

where $(a)_n$ denotes the [Pochhammer symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol).

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you attempted? What are the summation bounds?

Comment: summation from zero to infinity

Answer (score 6):

The above series represents [generalized hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function), but it is not related to the [Gauss's hypergeometric  function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

This particular series represents ${}_0F_{1}(;a;z)$ (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function#The_series_0F1)), and is related to Bessel function:
$$
  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!} \frac{1}{(a)_n} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!} \frac{\Gamma(a)}{\Gamma(a+n)}  = \Gamma(a) z^{\frac{1-a}{2}} I_{a-1}\left(2 \sqrt{z} \right)
$$
where $I_\nu(z)$ denotes the [modified Bessel function of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions_%3a_I.CE.B1.2C_K.CE.B1).

Comment: @MAK Since you are new to math.SE, and if you like this site, please browse through the [FAQ](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq). Great/interesting questions and answers get recognized by up-voting (clicking the up-arrow to the left of the question/answer). One of the answers extended ultimately becomes accepted (by clicking the tick symbol to the left of the answer), if it indeed answered the question. Accepting answers [is important](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers) part of site workflow.